# can someone please explain what is wrong in this c++ code and provide a solution

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have declared a class Products and another class CD the class CD is inheriting the class Products.
Now I have declared an constructor to update the value of the. and I am getting an error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Products
{
private:
  std::string name;
  std::string type;
  double price;
public:
  virtual std::string getname();
  virtual double getprice();
  virtual void show();
  std::string gettype()
  {
    return type;
  }
};

class CD: public Products
{
private:
  std::string artist;
  std::string studio;
public:

  CD(std::string sname,double sprice,std::string sartist,std::string sstudio)
  {
    this->type = "CD";
    this->name = sname ;
    this->price = sprice;
    this->artist = sartist;
    this->studio = sstudio;
  }
  
  void show()
  {
    std::cout<<"\nName of the CD:\t"<<this->name;
    std::cout<<"\nArtist of the CD:\t"<<this->artist;
    std::cout<<"\nStudio of the CD:\t"<<this->studio;
    std::cout<<"\nPrice of the cd:\t"<<this->price;
  }
  
};


int main()
{
CD obj("Oceans",49,"somesinger","somestudio");
}
```

ERROR :

In constructor 'CD::CD(std::string, double, std::string)';

'std::string Products::type' is private within this context

```
this->type="CD";
```

'std::string Products::name' is private within this context

```
this->name=sname;
```

'double Products::price' is private within this context

```
this->price= sprice;
```

Basically it is not giving error for the private data members of the CD class but just the data members that are being inherited from Products Class

Comment: Which part of "type is a private class member" is unclear to you, for example?

Comment: `CD` doesn't have access to private members of its base class. That's kinda the point of `private`.

Comment: type is just a data member @Sam Varshavchik

Comment: Use a getter. Inside Products have a void setType(std::string type) { this->type = type; }. Inside CD() ... { this->setType("CD");}

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik
How can I change the code so that I will be able to inherit those members but as well as update them in child class

Comment: Yes, it is. And, more importantly, it's a "private class member". Do you know what that means? You must've, since you used the `private` keyword, so you must be aware of what it does. So, what exactly is unclear, here?

Comment: Okay What I want to to know is there a way I can use the "name" "type" and "price" data members in the child classes.

Since I am inheriting the class Products into CD I want to change the values of those data members that are being inherited from the class Products.

Comment: Tip: It's time to learn about [constructor lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) as this would cut down dramatically on how much duplication you have here.

Comment: Maybe you meant `protected` as in "derived classes have full access to these fields" instead of `private` which means "get off my lawn you dumb kids!"

Comment: Open your text-book and read about the differences between `private`, `protected`, and `public`.

Comment: Okay what I understand from inheritance is once you inherit a class into another class. the Child Class now has has its own data member and the once inherited.

Now in the child class How do I access the data members that are inherited from the base class

Comment: There are at least three ways to do it, but you must understand the problem first.

Comment: The constructor of `CD` cannot directly access private members of `Product`. It shouldn't even try. One option is for `Product` to provide a non-`private` (i.e. either `public` or `protected`) constructor that initialises its own members.  Another option is for `Product` to provide non-`private` member functions `CD`s constructor may call to set members of the base.  A third option (NOT recommended) is to change members of `Produce` to be `public`. If you insist on not modifying the base class (to add non-`private` constructor or member functions) then there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Products
{
    private:
      std::string m_name;
      std::string m_type;
      double m_price;
public: 
  // No need for your setters/getters to be virtual 
  // if the derived class won't override anything or not
  const std::string& getType() const { return m_type; }
  const std::string& getName() const { return m_name; } 
  double getPrice() const { return m_price; } 


  void setType(const std::string& new_type) { m_type = new_type; }
  void setName(const std::string& new_name) { m_name = new_name; }
  void setPrice(double new_price) { m_price = new_price; }
  
  // Force derived class to override function
  virtual void show() = 0;
};

class CD: public Products
{
private:
  std::string artist;
  std::string studio;
public:

  CD(std::string sname,double sprice,std::string sartist,std::string sstudio)
  {
    this->setType("CD");
    this->setName(sname) ;
    this->setPrice(sprice);
    this->artist = sartist;
    this->studio = sstudio;
  }
  
  void show()
  {
    std::cout<<"\nName of the CD:\t"<<this->getName();
    std::cout<<"\nArtist of the CD:\t"<<this->artist;
    std::cout<<"\nStudio of the CD:\t"<<this->studio;
    std::cout<<"\nPrice of the cd:\t"<<this->getPrice();
  }
  
};


int main()
{
    CD obj("Oceans",49,"somesinger","somestudio");
    obj.show();
}
```

I want you to understand some changes here. First the removal of virtual keyword. In your case the setters/getters had no need to be virtual, as they were not being overriden or didn't have  a need to be based on the current example. Second, the setters/getters are setup to access the private members accordingly. We now use these functions within class CD. Also we changed the function show() to be pure virtual notice the = 0 at the end. I added a comment saying this forces derived classes to override the function. Lastly, your main wasn't doing anything so I added a obj.show() to actually print something.

Comment: Those are added as virtual as this is not the entire program. This is just a single part of a entire Stock Management program it didn't seem meaningful to put the entire project out her so I just written the part that is causing the error.


Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, I've added a constructor for `Products`, and `CD`'s constructor calls it to initialize the members that are private to `Products`.

I removed the `virtual` on `getName` and `getPrice` since these features don't change other products.

`show` remains virtual, and I split it into a piece in `Products` and a piece in `CD` so they each display their respective fields.  This separates the printing according to where the variables are, so for example, another class derived from `Products` wouldn't have to reimplement printing of name and price.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Products
{
private:
  std::string name;
  std::string type;
  double price;
public:
  std::string getname(); // Does not need to be virtual, as it's not overriden
  double getprice(); // Also does not need to be virtual
  virtual void show() const {
    std::cout<<"\nName of the " << type << ":\t"<<this->name;
    std::cout<<"\nPrice of the " << type << ":\t"<<this->price;
  };
  Products (const std::string &stype, double sprice, const std::string &sname)
  : name (sname), type (stype), price (sprice) {
  }
  std::string gettype() const
  {
    return type;
  }
};

class CD: public Products
{
private:
  std::string artist;
  std::string studio;
public:

  CD(const std::string &sname,double sprice, const std::string &sartist, const std::string &sstudio)
  : Products ("CD", sprice, sname)
  {
    artist = sartist;
    studio = sstudio;
  }
  
  void show() const override
  {
    Products::show(); // Call parent show() to show the basics
    std::cout<<"\nArtist of the " << gettype() << ":\t"<<this->artist;
    std::cout<<"\nStudio of the " << gettype() << ":\t"<<this->studio;
  }
  
};

int main()
{
    Products shoe ("Shoe", 3.49, "Nike runner");
    shoe.show();
    
    CD obj("Oceans",49,"somesinger","somestudio");
    obj.show();

}
```